# Why is it that when I view the source of a webpage, some information seems to be missing from when I inspect an element?

Tags: parsing, html

I am trying to parse through html files to get weather forecasts. However, when I view the source, the numbers are missing. When I view the element, the numbers are present. This is an example:

When inspect element: 
As seen the temperate is 33.2!
[image]
When view source:

div class="st-otlk-temp st-otlk-box-l mapInfoBoxS bFontEn posAbsolute" tt-title="Temperature">

What is the reason for this and how can I solve this for me to be able to parse through?

Note:I would like saving the source file and then parsing.

Comment: That content is probably added later on via JavaScript …

Comment: any content that is dynamically added.modified/removed via javascript and/or ajax, will show up differently in the actual page (inspected) versus the initial source (view source)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source is just a static content of a URL whereas inspect element will be changed dynamically based on user interaction

I guess in this case the temperatures will be loaded on load of actual web page

Comment: Is there any way to get around this for me to reach my goal? Perhaps an api.

Comment: If you have single page then get data from inspect element itself, If you have multiple pages and you want to write a script for that then view web page and check from which javascript/ajax that data is getting populated there. Query that request directly and get data from there